# How do I consume a paginated api in parallel?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm querying a paginated API with requests in a while loop sequentially. I know how many total items there are and the max number of items per response is 200. I can also calculate the offsets. This is quite slow however, I'd like to make the requests in parallel but research has shown that there is something called a global interpreter lock and appending data to a global list by multiple processes is error prone.

What's the most pythonic way to achieve this?

```py
def downloadUsers(token, totalUsers):
    offset = 0 
    limit = 200  
    authToken = token
    has_more = True
    allUsers = []

    while has_more:
        batch = offset + limit
        if batch > totalUsers:
            batch = totalUsers
        url = f"https://example.com/def/v1/users?offset={offset}&limit={limit}"
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': authToken}).json()

        allUsers.extend(response["data"])
        offset += 200
        has_more = response['has_more']

    allUsers = doSomethingElse(allUsers)
    return allUsers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that there is a the famous GIL. 
However, this block your python application to **use** only one thread. And the term use is very important. 
Because during the application, sometimes python delegate tasks to other system and wait for an answer. 
In you case, you are waiting for network connection to be established.

You can realize multi-threading of application by using the future class from the concurrent module.

it would be something like this:

`````
from concurrent import futures
maxWorker = min(10,len(total_amount_of_pages)) ## how many thread you want to deal in parallel. Here 10 maximum, or the amount of pages requested.
urls = ['url'*n for n in total_amount_of_pages] ## here I create an iterable that the function will consume.
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(workers) as executor:
                res = executor.map(requests.get,urls) ## it returns a generator
## it is consuming the function in the first argument and the iterable in the 2nd arguments, you can send more than 1 argument by adding new ones (as iterable). 
myresult = list(res)

````
`````

Comment: Cheers. I've used your example and combined it with the one in the Concurrent.Futures documentation to make it work to my liking.